# How can you profile the number of CPU used by your MATLAB program on Ubuntu

Tags: multithreading, matlab, ubuntu, parallel-processing

Is there a way to get the usage of CPU cores and the time percentage of CPU core usage during the whole execution of the program inside MATLAB?